# How do I get a ShockwaveFlashObject to display on a TabControl?

Tags: c#, flash, visual-studio-2012

I decided to switch a finished project to a tabbed layout, and I got everything working, except that my shockwaveflashobject plays the music from the videos it's executing but no longer the video, it just stays black. Before being put on the tab, the video displayed perfectly. Is there a setting I need to adjust on either the tabcontrol, tabpage, or shockwaveflashobject to allow the video to show?

Comment: I tried dragging the object off the tab and testing it... worked like a champ... when it's on the tab control, it stays black.

Comment: This is my last bug, to get the program fully polished and ready to submit. I've been looking for answers and poking it all night and just having no luck.